# ICU Layout sample renders text differently than Microsoft Notepad and Word

Tags: c++, icu, bidirectional, bidi

I have a bidirectional text

```
1002   -ابو ماجد الانصاري
```

Most editors notepad++, notepad etc. show the text as it is shown here. But when I get this text processed through ICU the number is shifted to the right then spaces and hyphen and then Arabic. ICU's sample application layout.exe also shows the number on the right.
I have modified paragraphlayout.cpp and set all possible reordering modes but result is still the same:

[image: See Problem Text here]

Can someone help to configure ICU to provide output as other display engines do.

Comment: Why so C and C++ tags? You will get down votes for that. Keep it more specific to one language.

Comment: How are you processing the text? Can you give a code sample of what you're doing?

Comment: @mnistic Layout.exe is a sample application included in ICU's samples. It also shows the number on the right. It can be downloaded from [ICU Website](http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/59.1/icu4c-59_1-src.zip)

Comment: Mixing Western punctuation and LTR text with Arabic RTL text is never not a problem.  You can't expect the text renderer to always get that right, whatever version of "right" you favor.  Sometimes "left" is better :)  Be sure to include hints so the renderer knows what you want, U+200E and U+200F.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your text 'begins' with the numeric, which is followed by the hyphen and text. Notepad and other editors let you choose the 'writing direction'. If you choose right-to-left, you get the same result as your screenshot,

[image: RTL screenshot]

If you want to maintain left-to-right writing direction, you can set it explicitly

```
ubidi_setPara(para, "1002   -ابو ماجد الانصاري", ‭25, UBIDI_LTR, NULL, pErrorCode);
```

or you can embed a UNICODE flag U+202A ([LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)) into your string that will enforce this direction. If your code is in C++, you can write something like

```
icu::UnicodeString string_to_layout = "\x202a";
string_to_layout += "1002   -ابو ماجد الانصاري";
```

and not you can use `string_to_layout` as input parameter for `renderParagraph()` (see http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c-latest/ubidi_8h.htm).

Comment: Thank you @Alex Cohn this worked. I was using UBIDI_DEFAULT_LTR.